# How to always display the url in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, url

I am currently working on a small paper, in which I need to include the sources via BibTeX. For every source, when applicable, I need to include the url of the website. However, when I try this, the url never get's included, in fact, only the title gets written. Can anybody help? Here's my code for one of the sources:

```
@misc{calciumchlorid,
    type = {chemie.de},
    title = {Calciumchlorid},
    howpublished = \url{https://www.chemie.de/lexikon/Calciumchlorid.html},
    urldate = {2021-10-17},
}
```

I saved the sources under Quellen.bib and created the bibliography with the following commands:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Quellen}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you use style `plainnat` instead `plain`?

Comment: Yes, but it still only shows me the title, but instead of [1], [cal()] appears in the bibliography.

Comment: If you can use `biblatex`, it defines a `url` field for the .bib file.